# Write to gnome terminal in java

Tags: java, linux, terminal, gnome

I'm trying to, through a java program, write commands in the gnome terminal. I tried this code:

```
    String cmd = "ls"; 
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process p = rt.exec(cmd);
```

I'm trying to write "ls" to the terminal but nothing happens, but if I use

```
    String cmd = "gnome-terminal";
```

I can open  a new terminal window.
What I really want to do is run a C program from the terminal, calling it with java.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it work with `/bin/ls` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gnome-terminal` takes the `-e` argument, which allows you to tell it to execute a program.

```
gnome-terminal -e /path/executable
```

Just put them in a `String[]` and call the same method.

Comment: Thanks it worked just fine, but now I have another problem, the program requires the terminal to be in full screen, do you how i can manage to do this?

Comment: I don't know that there's any way to programmatically have GNOME Terminal run in full screen.

Answer (score 1):

executing an external program works for me with the following commands:

```
try
 {
 Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
 Process proc = rt.exec("ls -l");
 InputStream in = proc.getInputStream();
 OutputStream out = proc.getOutputStream();
 InputStream err = proc.getErrorStream();
 proc.destroy() ;
}
```

Or, something similar is solved here: [Executing in java code an external program that takes arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921621/executing-in-java-code-an-external-program-that-takes-arguments) as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you're starting your java program from within a terminal then, after you've called `exec()` on the runtime, and get [a `Process`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) you need to call the `getInputStream()` to read the output of the command, then you can print it out to System.out.

Answer (score 0):

How I can read in this forum:
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/run-command-in-new-gnome-terminal-185216/

you can use

```
gnome-terminal -x sh -c "ls"
```

to open a terminal and execute "ls" (if i remember, the "-c" option can execute a program in a new terminal.)

In this moment I'm at work and I haven't linux X system to try here. Sorry :)

I hope that this can help you!

Comment: You don't need to run a shell to run another executable though.

Comment: Thanks works just fine!! Do you happen to know the arguments to open the terminal directly in full screen?

Comment: Try add "--full-screen" option before "-x".